# django 2.0 using MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I was curious about using MySQL instead of SQLite for my Django project. Firstly, I would like to ask: where can I find an explicite guide of how to install MySQL with Django on Windows and if I use MySQL, will I type the exact type of code I would usually type in SQLite ?
For example:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()
```

When you type this in Django, it gets converted to:

```
CREATE TABLE "books_publisher" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "address" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "city" varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    "state_province" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "country" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "website" varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

So the same will be when using MySQL ?

Comment: Yes. Why would you think it would be different?

Comment: I just thought I would be needed to type raw code. Also, for my first question, do you have an answer ? @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DannM  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes , note out that wheel  will be required for mysqlclient on windows